# Как можно на svg нарисовать бесконечную линию зная две её точки?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg

Как можно на svg нарисовать бесконечную линию зная две её точки?
Мне нужно чисто визуальное отображение, но со всеми стилями для линии.

```html
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
   <line x1="100" y1="80" x2="100" y2="20" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Точки линии, ширина, высота svg, viewBox могут меняться javascript'ом, но надо чтобы она в любом случае отображалась бесконечной. Желательно обойтись только HTML и CSS.

Comment: x1 и x2 - это координаты, и по любому есть начало и конец

Comment: > Желательно обойтись только HTML и CSS

А может задачу опишете? Может есть решение ни через SVG

Comment: @hisbvdis, нету прям конкретной задачи, просто балуюсь с svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бесконечную линию нарисовать вряд ли получится :), однако можно нарисовать линию на всем видимом диапазоне холста.

Для этого понадобится уравнение прямой:

> `y = kx + b`, где `k = dY/dX`

Подставим в это уравнение значения исходных точек, и выразим `y от х` и `x от y`

```
  k = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
  fX = x => y1 + (x - x1) * k
  fY = y => x1 + (y - y1) / k
```

Далее путем не хитрых подстановок находим точки пересечения прямой проходящей через исходные точки и границ холста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let x, y, cur;

document.querySelectorAll('circle').forEach(c => c.onmousedown = e => {
  cur = c;
  x = +c.getAttribute('cx') - e.x;
  y = +c.getAttribute('cy') - e.y;
});

addEventListener('mouseup', e => cur = null);

addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (!cur) return;
  cur.setAttribute('cx', x + e.x)
  cur.setAttribute('cy', y + e.y)
  move();
});

move();

function move() {
  let x1 = +p1.getAttribute('cx'),    
      y1 = +p1.getAttribute('cy'), 
      x2 = +p2.getAttribute('cx'),    
      y2 = +p2.getAttribute('cy'),
      w = +svg.getAttribute('width'), 
      h = +svg.getAttribute('height'),
      k = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1),
      fX = x => y1 + (x - x1) * k,
      fY = y => x1 + (y - y1) / k;
  let pt1 = check([0, fX(0)]);
  let pt2 = check([w, fX(w)]);    
  l.setAttribute('points', `${pt1[0]} ${pt1[1]} ${pt2[0]} ${pt2[1]}`);
  pA.setAttribute('cx', pt1[0]);
  pA.setAttribute('cy', pt1[1]);
  pB.setAttribute('cx', pt2[0]);
  pB.setAttribute('cy', pt2[1]);
  
  function check(p) {
    if (p[1] < 0) 
      return [fY(0), 0];
    if (p[1] > h) 
      return [fY(h), h];
    return p;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="170" style="border:solid">
   <polyline id="l" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></polyline>
   <circle id="p1" cx="100" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
   <circle id="p2" cx="200" cy="40" r="10"></circle>
   <circle id="pA" r="10" fill="red"></circle>
   <circle id="pB" r="10" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так же возможно получить подобный эффект за счет фокуса в svg, суть которого в применении многократного масштабирования, единственное что нужно посчитать, это центр между двумя исходными точками, относительно которого и необходимо масштабировать.

При этом так же необходимо установить атрибут `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`, который будет препятствовать визуальному увеличению толщины линии при масштабировании.

Но этот способ конечно хуже, т.к. когда точки близко друг к дружке, можно получить некорректный результат

```js
let x, y, cur;

document.querySelectorAll('circle').forEach(c => c.onmousedown = e => {
  cur = c;
  x = +c.getAttribute('cx') - e.x;
  y = +c.getAttribute('cy') - e.y;
});

addEventListener('mouseup', e => cur = null);

addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (!cur) return;
  cur.setAttribute('cx', x + e.x)
  cur.setAttribute('cy', y + e.y)
  move();
});

function move(){
  let x1 = +p1.getAttribute('cx'),    
      y1 = +p1.getAttribute('cy'), 
      x2 = +p2.getAttribute('cx'),    
      y2 = +p2.getAttribute('cy'),
      cx = (x1 + x2)/2, 
      cy = (y1 + y2)/2;
  l.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${cx},${cy})scale(1000)translate(${-cx},${-cy})`);
  l.setAttribute('points', `${x1} ${y1} ${x2} ${y2}`)
}

move();
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="170" style="border:solid">
   <polyline id="l" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></polyline>
   <circle id="p1" cx="100" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
   <circle id="p2" cx="200" cy="40" r="10"></circle>
</svg>
```